impoerted thunk was not found in redux-thunk
i see this error when i start the project "ERROR in ./src/redux/reducers/configureStore.js 7:57-62
export 'default' (imported as 'thunk') was not found in 'redux-thunk' (possible exports: thunk, withExtraArgument)" how i fix it?
enter image description here
I think it is about the version. I use react-router-dom@5.0.2 and redux-thunk@3.1.0

An image is not really appropriate in this context to help you debug, can you please edit your question to include the snippet of code instead of a screenshot please?

thunk is a named export in redux-thunk@3 like the error message informs you. That said, you really ought to update to Redux-Toolkit and stop using old and outdated Redux. RTK has Thunks built-in and enabled by default as well, so you import less and write about 50% less boilerplate code.
